# Fetch data from database using json without using an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I would like to retrieve objects from the database in JSON using PHP and MySql. I would just like to know how to do this without having to create an array? Can it be done?

If so, can I get an example of how that can be done with this draft piece of code?

```
$sql = "SELECT Email  , FirstName, LastName,Contact FROM tblUser where UserID=sessionID";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
    $arr = array(
        $row["Email"],
        $row["FirstName"],
        $row["LastName"],
        $row["Contact"]
    );

    array_push($json, $arr);
}

$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;
```

Comment: you have already answered your problem

Comment: I would like to avoid fetching an array because Im using this as a php server for my android app. I want to be able to access each record as an object rather than an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "select name,email from contact";

$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$num = mysqli_num_rows($res);

$json = array();
if($num > 0)
{
    while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($res))
    {
        $json[] = $obj;
    }
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

output:

```
 [{"name":"test","email":"test@gmail.cmom"},{"name":"test1","email":"test1@gmail.cmom"}]
```

Comment: please try my asnwer @CodeGirlAnon

Comment: if my answer solve your problem please mark answer @CodeGirlAnon

Comment: Sorry for taking so long... But it worked! I am so grateful to you @Pritamkumar